# Creating formulas out of a list of strings

Tags: r

I have the following code to parse a string into a list called `dag_str2`. It's coming out as a nested list and I would want it as just a regular list.

```
dag_str <- "dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}" 
dag_str2 <- gsub("dag|\\{|\\}|[[:space:]]","", dag_str) %>%
  str_split(";")

dag_str2
[[1]]
[1] "D<-G" "A<-D" "A<-G" "A<-Q"
```

I want the output to be a list of formulas like so
Output: List like this

```
"D~G" "A~D+G+Q"
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can continue to parse out your `dag_str2` to create your formula notation.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(str = unlist(dag_str2)) %>% 
  separate(str, c("lhs", "rhs"), sep = "<-") %>% 
  group_by(lhs) %>% 
  summarize(rhs = paste(rhs, collapse = "+"), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(f = paste(lhs, rhs, sep = "~"))
```

From here, you can convert to an actual formula easily if you need to.

```r
lapply(df$f, as.formula)
# [[1]]
# A ~ D + G + Q
# <environment: 0x000001af8db7fa20>
# 
# [[2]]
# D ~ G
# <environment: 0x000001af8db7fa20>
```

**Edit Based on Comments**

Here is one way to pull out the terms for which you want to build an intercept for.

There is just one new line, `bind_rows()`. This adds rows for the terms that are in the RHS, but not in the LHS.

```r
df <- tibble(str = unlist(dag_str2)) %>% 
  separate(str, c("lhs", "rhs"), sep = "<-") %>% 
  bind_rows(tibble(lhs = setdiff(.$rhs, .$lhs),
                   rhs = "1")) %>% 
  group_by(lhs) %>% 
  summarize(rhs = paste(rhs, collapse = "+"), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(f = paste(lhs, rhs, sep = "~"))
```

Comment: What does `.groups = "drop"` do?

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you! If I wanted to include every variable not included on the left hand side (G & Q) in this case. and put a 1 on the RHS for a intercept only model. Would this be difficult?

Comment: From this code `tibble(str = unlist(dag_str_split)) %>% 
  separate(str, c("lhs", "rhs"), sep = "<-") %>% 
  group_by(lhs)` I have a tibble. I want to add two new rows in this scenario with values of (G,1) and (Q,1).  `setdiff(df$rhs, df$lhs)` will give me G and Q, but i'm not sure how to add them to the tibble as rows

Comment: @Eisen I added an edit to add those rows. If you get more and more special cases, you may want to break these out into their own data frames instead of working in a single pipeline. But this is simple enough!

Answer (score 1):

You can try.

```
dag_str <- "dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}" 

x <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(strsplit(gsub("dag|[ {}]", "", dag_str), ";")[[1]], "<-"))
y <- aggregate(x[,2], list(x[,1]), paste, collapse="+")
paste(y[,1], y[,2], sep="~")
#[1] "A~D+G+Q" "D~G"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this for you :

```
dag_str2 <- gsub(pattern = "dag|\\{|\\}|[[:space:]]", replacement = "", x = "dag{D<-{G}; A<-{D}; A<-{G}; A<-{Q}}")

my_var <- str_split(string = dag_str2, pattern = ";", simplify = TRUE)

my_temp <- as.data.frame(my_var)
my_temp <- as.data.frame(t(my_temp))

my_var <- str_split(string = my_temp$V1, pattern = "<-", n = 2, simplify = TRUE)
my_temp$V1 <- my_var[, 1]
my_temp$V2 <- my_var[, 2]
my_temp <- my_temp[order(my_temp$V1, my_temp$V2),]
my_end <- my_temp %>% group_by(V1) %>% summarise(Test = paste(V2, collapse = "+"))
my_end$Result <- paste(my_end$V1, my_end$Test, sep = "~")
```